# How can i copy the current row of a model to other in Django?

Tags: python, django

**After I create a blog I have two submit buttons one to post an article in my profile which only I can see and other to post it in homepage as well as in my profile where all users can see but I can't figure out how to make second submit button work properly**

```
#Model MyLane in mylane/models.py
class MyLane(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
​
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
​
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('my-lane')

# Model Home in home/models.py
class Home(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(MyLane, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
​
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
​

​
#Createview in mylane/views.py
class MyLaneCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = MyLane
    fields = ['title', 'content']
​
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
​
    def get_success_url(self):
        if 'homepost' in self.request.POST:
            mylane = MyLane.objects.get("??")
            home = Home(title=mylane.title, content=mylane.content, author=self.request.user)
            home.save()
            url = reverse('home')
        else:
            url = reverse('my-lane')
        return url
```

​

Comment: Why not have 1 model with a boolean field that determines if it is public or not?

Comment: that thought never crossed my mind tbh thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at django signals, specially post_save, which allows you to do exactly what you want.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save

Comment: Thanks for these links, compared to the documentation(hard to understand) this blog is much more helpful